# How to add icon to Pycharm/setuptools-generated exe file (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, icons, setuptools, packaging

When using setuptools and the console_scripts method of producing a standalone Windows exe entry point for a python app, is it possible for setuptools to associate an icon (.ico) file to the exe it generates?

I'm using the Pycharm IDE with setup.py, setup.cfg, etc.